# How to hide button and disable button

Tags: ios, swift

I'm  trying to create small restaurant app for employees. There I have table numbers as a button if the user clicks that button I want that clicked button to be disabled and I want textfield and another ok button to appear. And if I click on disable button I want that to be enabled.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var total = 0
@IBOutlet weak var okButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var userInput: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userValue: UITextField!

@IBAction func okButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if userValue.text != nil{
    userInput.text = String(0)
    let userValueint: Int? = Int(userValue.text!)
    total = total + userValueint!
    let convertText = String(total)
    userInput.text = convertText
    userValue.text = String(0)
    userValue.isHidden = true
    okButton!.isHidden = true
   } else {
    print("Please Inter values")
   }
   }


  @IBAction func buttenPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    userValue.isHidden = false
    okButton.isEnabled = true
   }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userValue.isHidden = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     okButton.isHidden = false
  }
  }
```

So far I'm able to hide textField at the beginning and able to enabled when table button is clicked, but I can't hide ok button and disable the table button. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, thank you @matt. See my answer.

Comment: `userValue.text != nil` will always succeed

Comment: @matt ok, I get it but how can I make button disable or hide? override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        okButton.isEnabled = false
        
    } this is not working

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't clicked a disabled button. Second, use `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Ok, I use viewDidAppear to hide the ok button but is says "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: Actually, don't use viewDidAppear. Use viewDidLoad.

Comment: there is no such function viewDidLoad. What are you trying to say?

Comment: I mean, the viewDidLoad method: `override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad ... }`

Comment: I have a button name "ok", I tried two method 1. ok.isHideden = true and 2. ok.isEnabled = false none of them working. Got the error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Could please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: @putin make sure your outlets are connected properly.

Comment: @putin In your storyboard, check that the button is actually connected to your code. If you don't know what I mean, you can ask me questions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your table button is `sender` so disable sender and show ok button

```
@IBAction func buttenPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isEnabled = false
        userValue.isHidden = false
        okButton.isHidden = false
        okButton.isEnabled = true
       }
```